# how to compute linked Manipulates with a more efficient code

Tags: manipulate, code-request

I have several `Manipulate` codes as parts of a large block diagonal model. Each diagonal model produces outputs which are used in the second diagonal model, outputs of which are in turn used in the 3rd diagonal model and so on. I have a minimal example code as follows, which works just fine:

```
Row[{
  Manipulate[
   {
    Plot[Sin[a x + b], {x, 0, 6}],
    out1 = Sin[a x + b]
    },
   {{a, 2, "Multiplier"}, 1, 4},
   {{b, 0, "Phase Parameter"}, 0, 10}
   ],
  Spacer[40],
  Manipulate[
   {
    Plot[a x + Sqrt[out1], {x, 0, 6}],
    out2 = a x + Sqrt[out1]
    },
   {{a, 5, "Multiplier"}, 5, 10}
   ],
  Spacer[40],
  Manipulate[
   Plot3D[b y + Sqrt[out1] + Sqrt[out2] x^2, {y, 0, 6}, {x, 0, 6}],
   {{b, 1, "Multiplier"}, 1, 10}
   ]
  }]
```

When I change a parameter in the 1st `Manipulate`, the output generated is automatically used as an input in the 2nd `Manipulate` and then in the 3rd `Manipulate`

1. How can these separate `Manipulate`s be connected in a recursive manner and more efficiently, maybe with other codes like Block or While ...?
2. More troubling is how can I choose the `Manipulate` that I prefer to link to another `Manipulate` if there are more than 2 `Manipulate`s?

Comment: looks like a job for [TrackingFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrackingFunction.html)

Comment: Should ` out2 = a x + Sqrt[out]` read ` out2 = a x + Sqrt[out1]`? And what about `Sqrt[out1]` if  out1 is negative? Same for out2.

Comment: @Daniel Huber: You are right. It was a typo. I will correct it now. Better to have the real part of the imaginary number in case any of the outputs are `Sqrt[-1]`.

Answer (score 4):

It is unclear why you want multiple [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html). A single one will do everything that you show.

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

imgSize = 300;

Manipulate[
 Grid@{
   {Plot[Sin[a x + b], {x, 0, 6}, ImageSize -> imgSize],
    out1 = Sin[a x + b]},
   {Plot[c x + Sqrt[out1], {x, 0, 6}, ImageSize -> imgSize],
    out2 = c x + Sqrt[Sin[a x + b]]},
   {Plot3D[d y + Sqrt[out1] + Sqrt[out2] x^2, {y, 0, 6}, {x, 0, 6}, 
     ImageSize -> imgSize],
    out3 = d y + Sqrt[out1] + Sqrt[out2] x^2}},
 {{a, 2, "Multiplier"}, 1, 4, 0.25, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 0, "Phase Parameter"}, 0, 10, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{c, 5, "Multiplier 2"}, 5, 10, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{d, 1, "Multiplier 3"}, 1, 10, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {a, b, c, d}]
```

[image]

Comment: I perfectly understand your point. My question is a general question, not about the example given. I have already done what you showed in your answer. Since there are many instances I need to link `Manipulate`s from different notebooks, I was thinking there must be a clever way of doing this integration.